# Deriving property of OLS estimators: Simple Algebra

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

[![The sample cross product between each one of the regressors and the OLS
residuals is zero][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy8J7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy8J7.png)

Can anyone explain to me how the penultimate step leads to the final step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using the fact that
$$\hat \beta_2=\frac{\sum (X_i-\bar X)(Y_i-\bar Y)}{\sum (X_i-\bar X)^2}=\frac{\sum X_iY_i-n\bar X \bar Y}{\sum X_i^2-n\bar X^2}=\frac{\frac1n\sum X_iY_i-\bar X \bar Y}{\frac1n\sum X_i^2-\bar X^2}.$$

So $$\frac1n\sum X_iY_i-\bar X \bar Y-\hat \beta_2 \left(\frac1n\sum X_i^2-\bar X^2\right)=$$
$$=\frac1n\sum X_iY_i-\bar X \bar Y- \frac{\frac1n\sum X_iY_i-\bar X \bar Y}{\frac1n\sum X_i^2-\bar X^2} \cdot\left(\frac1n\sum X_i^2-\bar X^2\right)=$$
$$=\frac1n\sum X_i Y_i -\bar X \bar Y -\left(\frac1n\sum X_i Y_i -\bar X \bar Y\right)=0.$$

Comment: Ah ok, so I do have to substitute the second OLS estimator in - the adjacent terms do not in fact cancel out?

Comment: Sure, after that substitution everything cancels out with some other factor or term.